# Second tray icon message popup crashes app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm building an app that can be "minimized to tray" using Python 3 and PyQt5 on Linux. Once it's hidden and a message shown via `trayIcon.showMessage()` is dismissed, trying to show the second message causes a segmentation fault.

The app watches for changes to a file and notifies the user of occurrences of that match a particular regular expression. When it's hidden, the occurrences are shown to the user via messages with the tray icon.
At first I thought it was a result of some threading issue which occurs when the window is hidden due to messages like `QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread` in the console (and I have no clue why that happens, I didn't create any threads), so I decided to only update the window while it's visible, but that didn't work.

I was able to narrow it down to the line that triggers the message:

```
if self.trayIcon.isVisible():
    print("about to show message")
    print(self.fileContentsList[-1])
    self.trayIcon.showMessage(
        "New match!",
        self.fileContentsList[-1])
```

But I'm not sure why the segmentation fault happens. I've tried googling but it seems my case is somewhat unique. What could be the issue?

**EDIT:** something i forgot to add: running the app with strace (`strace python3 logwatch.py`) somehow stopped the segmentation fault from happening.

**EDIT2:** the code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/tehlordvortex/logwatch/

**EDIT3:** the specific line shown in PyCharm's console is: `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

**EDIT4:** it seems attaching it to any form a debugger prevents the crash. I tried PyCharm's debugger and valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was a threading issue as I had initially thought.

The Observer from the watchdog module runs on another thread, which is where the extra thread came from. I rewrote my Watch class to notify my Window via `queue.Queue` instead of calling the callback directly. That makes the callback run on the main thread instead.

The fix is outlined in [this commit](https://github.com/tehlordvortex/LogWatch/commit/6be1d6f7d84e94d4097c58b495a56911fdd37860). If there's a better way or another way, I would very much like to know.